# Cache Server like Redis Vs Static variable

Tags: c#, caching, static, stackexchange.redis

I wanna cache an array of object that is not more than 300 items, It's read only array.
First I implemented it in Redis with **StackExchange.Redis** client, and then implement it by static variable.
Static variable has e better performance and get less CPU usage instead of Redis, but I do not know that is it good way or not?

Comment: It's always about pros and cons. Should this variable live throughout the life-time of the application? Is it ever going to change?

Comment: This variables does not change after initialized. @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: Then if you perhaps need a key-value storage like redis, you can use a `Dictionary<K,V>` if it's being accessed from a single threaded application, or `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` if it's being accessed concurrently.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov , at first for me is important that is it good idea that use static variable in asp.net MVC web-api? and then witch type is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is truly static, then while *yes* you could store the data in redis, you would *not* usually go to redis every time - so it would probably end up having a local cache *anyway* (with redis as a second level cache). `static` can work fine for things like a read-only array, and this will be unbeatable in terms of performance. However, if you start mutating the contents of a `static` member: expect pain.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my project we used redis for caching and also we used local cache (Not static variable but you can also use static variable).

But it really depends on your requirements. We used redis because we had web farm and we wanted to share data between servers. We also used local caching ([see MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to increase performance.